# InsertStatement using SelectStatement in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying use insert but as one of parameters use result of select statement

```
 try {
      SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RentCarConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      conn1.Open();

      string selectQuery = "Select IDOsoby from Klienci Where Email = @Semail ";
      string insertQuery = "insert into Wypozyczenia (IdOsoby, IDCAR, DataWypozyczenia) values (@idOs, @idcar, @data)";
      string updateQuery = "Update Samochody SET CzyDostepny = 'False' Where IDCAR = @idCar";

      SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn1);
      SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn1);
      SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn1);

      com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semail", Session["New"]);

      com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idOs", selectQuery);
      com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCar", Session["S_polka"]);

      com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCar", Session["S_polka"]);
      com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());

      com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
      com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
      com3.ExecuteNonQuery();

      conn1.Close();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
```

Code working but into Wypozyczenia table It has been added IdOsoby as "It has been added". Please help how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

By this way, Combine the separate `Insert` and `Select` queries. Just use `Insert into..Select` syntax

```
insert into Wypozyczenia (IdOsoby, IDCAR, DataWypozyczenia) 
Select IDOsoby, @idcar, @data from Klienci Where Email = @Semail
```